# Set all none-use indexes empty inside array() in PHP

Tags: php

I have bunch of arrays which defined as bellow:

```
$exam1= array(1 => "XL",2=>"CD");  
$exam2= array(5 => "XLd",7=>"CDW");
```

Is there any predefined function in php which I can make all none-used index less than last index as empty.
let say  in the first example make index 0 empty.
or in second example make all 0,1,2,3,4,6 indexes empty.

It should looks as bellow:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(2) "XL" [2]=> string(0) "CD"}   
array(8) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(3) "XLd" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(3) "CDW" }
```

thanks

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: i show the var_dump

Comment: `2=>"CD"` is missed from the 1st array in your output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exist a specific function but you can get it using `array_fill_keys` function.

```
$exam2= array(5 => "XLd",7=>"CDW");

$max_key = max(array_keys($exam2));
$exam2 += array_fill_keys(range(0, $max_key), "");

var_dump($exam2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `array_fill_keys()` function:

```
$exam2= [5 => "XLd",7=>"CDW"];
$last = end($exam2);  // setting internal pointer of the array on its last item
$exam2 = $exam2 + array_fill_keys(range(0, key($exam2)), "");
ksort($exam2);   // sorting by keys

print_r($exam2);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => XLd
    [6] => 
    [7] => CDW
)
```